# minimal ffmpeg build without filters

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to build a minimal version of ffmpeg that is as small as possible, with only support to decode AAC audio in an MP4 container, and write it out to PCM or WAV.

For some reason though, I can't find a way to build ffmpeg without it including all of these filters:

```
Enabled filters:
aformat                 atrim                   hflip                   transpose               vflip
anull                   format                  null                    trim
```

Is there any way to disable these?

I'm using this configure command:

```
./configure \
        --disable-fast-unaligned \
        --disable-pthreads \
        --disable-w32threads \
        --disable-os2threads \
        --disable-debug \
        --disable-stripping \
        --disable-safe-bitstream-reader \
        --disable-all \
        --enable-ffmpeg \
        --enable-avcodec \
        --enable-avformat \
        --enable-avfilter \
        --disable-filters \
        --enable-protocol=pipe \
        --disable-swresample \
        --disable-swscale \
        --disable-network \
        --disable-d3d11va \
        --disable-dxva2 \
        --disable-vaapi \
        --disable-vdpau \
        --enable-protocol=file \
        --disable-bzlib \
        --disable-iconv \
        --disable-libxcb \
        --disable-lzma \
        --disable-sdl2 \
        --disable-securetransport \
        --disable-xlib \
        --disable-zlib \
        --enable-encoder=pcm_s16le \
        --enable-muxer=pcm_s16le,wav \
        --enable-demuxer=mov \
        --enable-libfdk-aac \
        --enable-nonfree \
        --enable-decoder=libfdk_aac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ffmpeg binary depends on libavfilter besides libavcodec and libavformat.

A few filters are selected to support some command-line options, e.g. trim/atrim for when input `-ss` is set and the streams are decoded, transpose and flip filters for when the input is to be autorotated. format/aformat for auto-inserted conversion from decoder output to encoder-supported format.